# Proper SE site to move the this Medical Sciences Question

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My sister is a General Practitioner and asked [this](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/23283/7965) question.

She is not familiar with the Medical Sciences Stack Exchange site rules and so I am not familiar with this field.

So I like to know how this question could be modified to be asked at the Medical Sciences SE site.

Because of her historical memory about that SE site and her being question banned there (become off topic) and saving my time, I prefer to ask here where one could ask this question.

Comment: There is no site in the SE network that will take that question. You can't ask for a diagnosis.

Comment: Downvoting the question seems to contradict much of the purpose of Meta. The OP has asked the question specifically because she doesn't know of a suitable SE site. Of course, there isn't one but that seems a poor reason to penalize the person for asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your sister should consult her colleagues, instead of asking advice from random strangers on the Internet. Google knows a lot (proof: half of my answers on Stack Exchange) but when I visit a GP, I hope he/she doesn't diagnose me by Googling. I could do that myself, keeping more than 1.5 meter distance in the process.

There's no Stack Exchange site for diagnosing single cases like this; consider us as a collection of [libraries](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/tour). If you want to improve the question so that it fits there, ask on [their own Meta](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/).